# GWT PopupPanel from iframe

Tags: gwt, iframe

I have a GWT Gadget which is hosted inside an iframe (as a Google Gadget).

I would like to open a GWT PopupPanel from within the Gadget, but which is centered on the entire browser window and not just the iframe.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you can get the iframe to get a little bigger. An iframe is a window, as far the code running in it is concerned, so your code can only measure the total height/width of the iframe, and can't draw outside of that window.

One possible exception could be opening a new window with `Window.open(...)`, but then you'd need to load something else there, a new page.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, that does seem to be the case.  Loading a new page at this stage is not an option, so I'll stick with keeping the UI contained within the iframe.